# Is there any other way to prove this statement?

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $v_1, ..., v_n \in R^m$, where $R^m = M_{m1}(R)$ for $R$ a commutative ring and $R^m$ a vector space. Let the matrix $A= [v_1 |...| v_n]$, the matrix whose $i$th column $= v_i$. I want to show that $A\cdot e_i = v_i$.

This is just a matrix multiplication problem I guess. So I let $$x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
\vdots\\ 
\
x_n
\end{bmatrix}.$$ So then I figured $A \cdot x = x_1 v_1 + \cdots + x_n v_n$. Now the canonical basis $$e_i = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
\vdots\\ 
0\\ 
1\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $1$ is in the $i$th place. So then it follows that $A \cdot e_i = 0v_1 + \cdots + v_i + 0v_{i+1} + \cdots + 0v_n = v_i$. I think this is correct, but could there have been perhaps a better and more different way to prove this?

Comment: This is correct, and is probably the most straightforward approach. Somehow I feel that any other approach will somehow reduce to this one, anyway.

Comment: What bothers you about how you've already proven it? Seems quite straightforward-though you shouldn't call $R^m$ a "vector space" when $R$ is only a ring. In general it's only a free module.